# Should we contact a professional to handle our bathroom repair?

Tags: repair, bathroom

Our upstairs bathroom is leaking to the ceiling drywall in our downstairs dining room.  The toilet and the tub need to be fixed. We need to take up the tile, floor board, maybe tub and fix it all. Then replace the flooring, retile and fix the ceiling. My husband thinks he can go it alone. I'm a little leery. Should we call a pro?

Comment: Do you know why it is leaking?  Kind of weird that both tub and toilet are both leaking - is husband fixing leak and does he have experience with plumbing?  For a person with low experience this is a 50-70 hour job at least.

Comment: If this is your sole full bath, hire someone. Unless your husband is taking a week of vacation for the project. Even if you have another shower, bath toilet etc, The stress of the whole family using one bath isn't worth the savings.

Comment: Note that you don't repair a leak in the plumbing below the floor by ripping up the floor anywhere but the basement. You open the ceiling below since that's typically drywall, already damaged, and significantly easier to repair.

Comment: The only way to answer this is to know your husband's skill set, experience, time available, access to materials, tools, etc. OR, the other way to answer it is: Are you filing a homeowners claim? If so, hire whoever they tell you to hire.

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing it solely to save money, then it's probably not a good idea. If you are ready to spend time to learn how to do it and enjoy diy, then there's no reason calling a "pro".

Comment: My husband wants to save money. He does not enjoy these things. He is easily frustrated

Comment: "He is easily frustrated" - I'd call in a pro! At least to fix the plumbing.

Comment: @Elizabeth you might try a hybrid, husband does demo, pros repair damage and prep for tile(new backerboard, waterproofing over backrboard (Liquid membrane/Kerdi)), you and husband do tile and grouting.